# cfif currentURL containing multiple URLS

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to add another domain to the CF if statement below.

```
<cfif currentURL CONTAINS 'foo'>
```

The desired if statement will add "alpha". This CF file is a shared resource amongst 4 domains and only 2 need to be updated with content within the IF statement. I tried the 2 examples below without prevail. Thank you in advance.

```
<cfif currentURL CONTAINS 'foo, alpha'>
<cfif currentURL CONTAINS 'foo,alpha'>
```

Comment: would this work? <cfif currentURL CONTAINS "foo" OR currentURL CONTAINS "alpha">

Comment: (Edit) What is an example of the `currentURL` value and which part of the URL are you trying to match? CONTAINS will match partial strings. For example contains "foo" will match all of these: "/foo/", "/snafoo/", "/food/" and "/xxxx/flood.cfm". Not sure if that is really the result you want ...

Comment: We were matching the root domain name. I could see the issue if it was any other internal page. Thank you for the heads up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<cfif currentURL CONTAINS 'foo' OR currentURL CONTAINS 'alpha'>
```

Comment: Would the person who downvoted this care to explain why?